# Inserting a file into another file at certain point

Tags: text-processing, sed

Using a bash script, I'm having difficulty trying place one file into another based on a certain location.

```
||bob
||mary
||david
```

destination:

```
||urty
! comment
||gdfgrw
||fdfdf
```

So basically drop all of the contents of one file into (below the ! comment) header:

So the destination should look like this:

```
||urty
! comment
||bob
||mary
||david
||gdfgrw
||fdfdf
```

Comment: What if there are multiple lines like `! comment` ? Do you want to insert only after the 1st one or after all of them ?

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/! comment/ r insertfile' destinationfile
||urty
! comment
||bob
||mary
||david
||gdfgrw
||fdfdf
```